# Nifi Data Enrichment using MongoDBLookup Service in Lookup Record Processor

Tags: mongodb-query, apache-nifi

I am trying to enrich my incoming flowfile with data from two different mongo collections. Can I configure the MongoDB Lookup Service in such a way that I access two different mongo collections within same processor group in Nifi.

Currently, I am not able to configure the Mongo service for more than one mongo collection.

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDBLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mongodb-services-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.mongodb.MongoDBLookupService/) will evaluate Expression Langauge and can reference FlowFile Attributes. So if the FlowFile contains an Attribute with the collection name, you can reference that.

However, it will only do one collection at a time, so if each Record needs 2 Lookups, you'll need to do 2 successive LookupRecords.